# Facing issue with Select Functionality of Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

During the automation flow, my scripts correctly identify the Dropdown object and selects based on the value passed.

```
public NewV1ProjectPage selectResponsiblePerson(String responsiblePersonValue){
    WebElement responsiblePerson = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
              .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.name("responsible_person_sap_id")));
    new Select(responsiblePerson).selectByVisibleText(responsiblePersonValue);
    return this;
}
```

But problem comes when it moves to next Dropdown, as soon as it moves to new dropdown the value selected in previous dropdown is deselected.

I am not sure what is causing the value to disappear from this dropdown, rest all the dropdowns are working fine..

Please somebody help!!!

Answer (score 0):

try below code may be helpful to you,

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id(""));
Select sortby = new Select(element);
List<WebElement> options =sortby.getOptions();
for (WebElement element1 : options) {
    // given the value in data place
if (element1.getText().equals(data)) {
         element1.click();
     Thread.sleep(5000);
    }
}
```

Comment: it is already selecting the value using my code.. the problem is value gets deselected automatically when driver moves to next dropdown.

Comment: yea tried that only.. sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: where exactly you want me to put wait.. its not working again.

Comment: After selecting the one value in drop down list, you give some Threadsleep then continue with next drop down list selecting.